# Pad shape for spring loaded pin

Tags: pcb, connector, terminal

I'm going to use spring loaded pins (https://www.digikey.com/products/en?keywords=811-SS-004-30-002101%20) for interconnection between miniPCIe and base board. They are going to be mounted on base board under miniPCIe board - we are using high connector so there is enough space for them - but I have no clue how to shape pads on miniPCIe board! Should I just make pads without solder mask?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make pads large enough that the pins still hit the target with any conceivable misalignment, and leave off soldermask.  Consider also what surface finish you want, some will provide better long term reliability and more mating cycles than others. Probably flash gold would be best, with ENIG okay and HASL not so good.

Comment: Agree that the surface finish is important. Most commectors have terminals that slide along the mating surface, removing oxidation to assure a clean connection. Your design does not have this feature.